# Cordova App is being killed after 4-5 hours

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I made app that gets the location from the employee and sends it to the server..

it is an customized app for a company, and will not be published in store..

i am using a Wake lock app(separately)  to do a partial wake-up call to my mobile so the CPU doesn't sleep, and my app can do the work in the background..

The problem is that even after using partial wake lock.. the app is being killed by the system after 4-5 hours..

is it because of low memory.. ?
how can I handle this ? 
I am testing it on Samsung s4, android 5.0.1 .

thanks

Comment: You might want to describe in detail what your separate 'Wake lock app' is doing, how long does it hold a lock, and how your webapp is related. Although I expect that if it is the webapp in the background then the system is killing it as a part of normal operations when memory/resources gets low.

Comment: I am using a Wake lock app separately installed.. this has no interaction with my app.. it is just to keep my cpu alive..

So if the system is killings it as a part of normal operation, any idea how can i handle this.. ? Can i restart my application automatically once it is killed by the system?

Comment: pls @ Hus ,can you help me post your project source code .have been working on something like this but i just don`t have it working. I will be grateful if you can share  the code.